# How do I fix hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Suspend and Hibernate was not working in my Ubuntu 11.04 and I followed [these instructions](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/fix-for-suspend-and-hibernation-problem-for-laptops.html) to fix the issue by installing `uswsusp`.

The commands `s2ram` and `s2disk` were working fine for me and hence I replaced the contents of `hal-system-power-suspend-linux` and `hal-system-power-hibernate-linux` as directed in the above link.

Now after my upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10, I am unable to hibernate my system. How to rectify this issue? Is there any config file which I need to change for hibernate to function properly?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure that your swap is mounted correctly. Edit the `/etc/fstab/` file using the nano editor:

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

When the /etc/fstab is opened, go to the line where you can read: ” # swap was on /dev/…..” immediately after this line, I mean the next line, be sure there is no ”#”. If there is a ”#” starting this following line, just delete it. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and after that <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes you made to fstab, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano. Now your swap space will be active for hibernation after the next reboot.

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

...and restart your computer.

Comment: Hi, the hibernate problem was recctified automatically. Now am able to suspend and hibernate without any issues. Anyways, thanks for your reply. It might be usefull for others.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `uswsusp` saved me. I'm still unclear on whether or not it is cleaner to use `swsusp` as mentionned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate) but for now, it will totally do!

Comment: After taking the above steps, my ubuntu takes forever to start. The five dots below ubuntu keep on running indefinitely. help!!