# Why won't my computer hibernate and shut down properly?

Tags: power-management, hibernate, swap

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and hibernate isn't working on this machine.

I looked at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66879/fix-hibernate-issue-in-ubuntu-11-10) and after the string `# swap was on /dev/…..` nothing appears.

I cannot find the file: `/usr/lib/hal/scripts/linux/hal-system-power-suspend-linux`. Moreover, `s2disk` does not work properly and the computer cannot hibernate.

Now I cannot even shut down the system - the process does not complete. I need to press the power button every time.

Answer (score 2):

Try mount the swap partition (sd* is your swap partition - if you don't know what it is, probably it's the one in the comment "# swap was on /dev/...")

```
sudo swapon /dev/sd*
```

and suspend.
You should also post more information about your machine.

Answer (score 0):

this page recommends you have at least as much swap space as you do RAM... I only had 1G swap, vs 8G RAM, so that could be the problem!

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#Why_do_I_need_swap.3F

[edit] - tried this, made sure I had swap to spare (10GB for 8GB RAM), still doesnt work :(