# Booting failed after enabling swap and installing uswsusp

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap, hibernate

After **reinstalling *Ubuntu 15.04***, my swap partition was not active which is why Ubuntu did not hibernate. I followed steps given in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/73479/329036) .

I edited `/etc/fstab/` by typing `sudo nano /etc/fstab` in the terminal. Then removed the hash tag `#` from below  `# swap was on /dev/…` and saved it and exited it.

Then I installed `uswsusp` from terminal by using `sudo apt-get install uswsusp` .
After I restarted, all hell broke loose. Ubuntu now takes forever to load. The five dots below **ubuntu** just keep running forever.

Comment: Anybody, any idea?